# How to select all rows from the oracle PL/SQL collection into SYS_REFCURSOR

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Note: I have seen many solution and all says I can not use SQL with a PL/SQL type. I must have to use CREATE or REPLACE, but my restriction is I can not use system object for this task.

What I have tried the below example returns only last row.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_TEST (TEST_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)IS
 TYPE TEMP_RECORD IS RECORD(
                    entries   NUMBER,
                    name      VARCHAR2(50),
                    update    VARCHAR2(200)
                );
TYPE TEMP_TABLE IS TABLE OF TEMP_RECORD INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
VAR_TEMP       TEMP_TABLE;
IDX            PLS_INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN 
VAR_TEMP(IDX).cur_entries := 1;
VAR_TEMP(IDX).cur_entries := 2;
 OPEN TEST_cursor FOR
 SELECT VAR_TEMP(idx).cur_entries from dual;
END SP_TEST;
```

Another way tried.

```
OPEN TEST_cursor FOR
  SELECT * FROM TABLE(VAR_TEMP)
--- It gives compilation error ora-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you can't create an object in the database, the only solution I can think of is to use dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE TYPE temp_record AS OBJECT
(
    entries NUMBER,
    entry_name VARCHAR2 (50),
    update_value VARCHAR2 (200)
);

CREATE TYPE temp_table IS TABLE OF temp_record;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test (test_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
    var_temp temp_table := temp_table ();
    strSql  VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    -- Populate the temp table, or pass it in from elsewhere

    var_temp.EXTEND();
    var_temp (var_temp.LAST).entries := 1;
    var_temp (var_temp.LAST).entry_name := 'test';

    FOR i IN 1..var_temp.COUNT LOOP
      strSql := strSql ||
                  CASE
                    WHEN LENGTH(strSql) > 0 THEN ' UNION ALL '
                    ELSE NULL
                  END ||
                  'SELECT ' || var_temp.ENTRIES || ' ENTRIES,' ||
                            '''' || var_temp.ENTRY_NAME || ''' ENTRY_NAME FROM DUAL';
    END LOOP;

    OPEN test_cursor FOR strSql;
END sp_test;
```

Now, I may have messed up the string concatenation logic there a bit, but the objective is to end up with an SQL string which looks something like

```
SELECT 1 ENTRIES,'test' ENTRY_NAME FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ENTRIES,'test 2' ENTRY_NAME FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 ENTRIES,'test_3' ENTRY_NAME FROM DUAL
```

but, of course, without the nice white space and etc.

The 32K limit on dynamic SQL may bite you eventually, but if push comes to shove you can the DBMS_SQL package to handle arbitrarily large SQL text, although that presents its own challenges.

Best of luck.

Comment: Probably you need to be careful if this procedure is called often, due the hard parsing and associated library cache issues.

Comment: Thanks @Bob, One more help how can I use into with the same example i.e. SELECT ENTRIES,NAME INTO VAR_TEMP FROM SOME_TABLE.

Comment: Please write that up as a separate question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reference types in SQL (as opposed to PL/SQL), they must be created as objects in the database. This is effectively a scope issue: when you run SQL you are shifting to a different context. Any structures that you have created locally are not available there.

```
CREATE TYPE temp_record AS OBJECT
(
    entries NUMBER,
    entry_name VARCHAR2 (50),
    update_value VARCHAR2 (200)
);

CREATE TYPE temp_table IS TABLE OF temp_record;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_test (test_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
    var_temp temp_table := temp_table ();
BEGIN
    var_temp.EXTEND ();
    var_temp (var_temp.LAST).entries := 1;
    var_temp (var_temp.LAST).entry_name := 'test';

    OPEN test_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE (var_temp);
END sp_test;
```

Comment: I already mentioned I can not create this in database level. looking for something like if there any function logic that can return array so that select will work.

Comment: 1) A procedure is an object. 2) You cannot load a cursor (by definition SQL) from a local user-defined type.

Comment: Let me clear more, the need is to replace global temp table with the alternate solution because we don't want manage these dependencies. Now if i will use two more objects from the DB level, the alternate will create more dependencies rather than previously.